# Train errors about ssd-windows

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

When I use `ssd-microsoft` branch to train on windows 10,the author is called conner 99 in Github. I meet an error:

> Error parsing text -format caffe.NetParameter:29:19:Message
>   type"caffe.TransformationParameter"has no field named "distort_param".

and the "distort_param" in `train.prototxt` is as follows:

```
distort_param{
    brightness_prob:0.5
    brightness_delta:32
    contrast_lower:0.5
    contrast_upper:1.5
    hue_prob:0.5
    hue_delta:18
}
```

Anyone can tell me what's the meaning of `distort_param`, and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: AFAIK SSD has its own training data augmentation function and this parameter is a part of it.

Comment: why do you insist on working on a Windows branch? the Linux branch works fine just out of the box...